# Thousands of radio buttons cause low performance in WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, virtualization, uniformgrid

I need to create an user control that displays the wafer map, so I used a ListBox with uniform grid and each cell represents a die in the wafer. The problem I got is that when there are too many dies, for example, 100*100 uniformgrid, will be super slow to display, and also the scroller view is slow.
Below is my code:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" x:Name="WaferMapGrid" Columns="{Binding MapColumnCount}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Rows="{Binding MapRowCount}" Background="AliceBlue" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Loaded="WaferMapGrid_Loaded">
                                <UniformGrid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="WaferMapScaleForm" ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=ZoomSlider}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=ZoomSlider}" />
                                </UniformGrid.LayoutTransform>
                            </UniformGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="WaferMapScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Loaded="WaferMapScrollViewer_Loaded" ScrollChanged="OnScrollViewerScrollChanged" PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseWheel="WaferMapScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" PreviewMouseMove="OnMouseMove" PreviewMouseUp="OnMouseLeftButtonUp" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Padding="0">
                                <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="4"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ScrollViewer.Resources>
                                <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <RadioButton x:Name="Die" MinHeight="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Background="{Binding TestState,Converter={StaticResource TestStateConverter}}" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0.5" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" GroupName="DieGroup" Style="{StaticResource DieStyle}" Margin="0" Content="{Binding DisplayText}" >
                                    <RadioButton.ToolTip>
                                        <local:DieInfo></local:DieInfo>
                                    </RadioButton.ToolTip>
                                </RadioButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

By the way, the Virtualization seems not working in uniformgird. Any one knows how to optimize my code to improve the proformance? Attach the screen shot of my application:

[image]

Comment: Setting those VirtualizingPanel attached properties has no effect on a UniformGrid because it is no VirtualizingPanel.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after searching around in Stackoverflow. Just don't know what can I do to improve the performance now

Comment: i tried with a similar example with 200 x 200 and while it takes a long time (20s) to create, scrolling and resizing is fast. I used a rectangle with color because listbox has selection built in. i guess some "unnessesary" things in your xaml make it slow.

Comment: To speed up loading, you can e.g. initialize cell's data contexts on a background thread, and use Dispatcher with a low priority. That way, if you load cells data contexts one by one, you won't freeze the UI at the beginning. To improve scrolling performance, try BitmapCache.

Comment: Thanks Firo and Maciek, I will try it.